# Treatment of acid attack by milk

Tags: acid-base, safety

I saw a post on Facebook saying if acid falls on some body part instantly wash it by milk but after a search on google I got [this link](https://www.quora.com/Does-pouring-milk-on-the-acid-attacked-area-help) which says it will actually worsen the condition.

Now I'm confused. Is milk 'good' or 'bad' for acid on the skin?

Comment: This seems close to personal medical advice. But, if I spilled a concentrated acid on my skin and only had a glass of milk at hand, I pour the milk on and then go find the emergency shower. No, just _why_ I'd have a glass of milk nearby while doing chemistry is a different question...

Comment: Which acid? It's not like there's no difference...

Comment: @JonCuster The glas of milk is on the bench, right between the open beaker with fuming nitric acid and the plate with the cookies ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Treatment" of acid burns by pouring milk over it falls into the same category as

- drinking milk in the case of intoxications
- covering burns with flour or shaving cream

All these "household remedies" are not recommended by modern medical standards and **should be avoided**.

*Jon Custer*'s tongue-in-cheek comment is right. At a place where you work with concentrated acids, a glas of milk should not be easier to reach than a huge sink with a water tap.

In addition, proper eye protection and acid-resistent gloves are advised!

You will not find the suggestion to use milk in any recent occupational safety first aid guide!

The [DGUV Information 204-008 (PDF, German)](http://publikationen.dguv.de/dguv/pdf/10002/204-008.pdf), a first aid handbook for schools and kindergardens explicitely states on p. 106 ff that the proper procedure to treat others with acid burns is:

1. protect yourself (rubber gloves)
2. remove all clothes that were in contact and soaked with the acid
3. wash the affected areas with lots of warm water until the pain has ceased
4. if necessary, call an ambulance

Comment: Ok i got it but just out of curiosity can milk really cause any harm as stated on the link provided in question.